# C++ reading in Files. No Class/Struct/Union

Tags: c++

I am having an error that says on line 61 that left of open must have a class/struct/union. I also have the same error on line 78. I am working in visual studio 2013. I am confused on why I need to redefine what class it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std; 

struct recordPlayer
{
    string id, firstname, lastname, division, team;
    int platApp, atBats, singles, doubles, triples, homers, sacks, walks, hitbyPitch;
    double battingAvg, onBase, Slugging;
    int totalHit, totalBases;
};
struct playerUpdate
{
    string update;
    string id, firstname, lastname, division, team;
    int platApp, atBats, singles, doubles, triples, homers, sacks, walks, hitbyPitch;
    float battingAvg, onBase, Slugging;
    int totalHit, totalBases;
};

bool newPlay(char x);
bool delPlay(char x);
bool updatePlay(char x);
int playerId(string x, recordPlayer y[], int fileSize);
void equalThem(recordPlayer x[], playerUpdate y[], int location, int fileSizeTwo);
void deleteThem(recordPlayer x[], playerUpdate y[], int location, int fileSizeTwo);
void determineStats(recordPlayer x[], int fileSize);

ofstream& operator << (ofstream& outdata, recordPlayer data)
{
    outdata << data.id << "/t" << data.firstname << "/t" << data.lastname << "/t" << data.division << "/t" << data.team << "/t" << data.platApp << "/t" << data.atBats << "/t" << data.singles << "/t" << data.doubles << "/t" << data.triples << "/t" << data.homers << "/t" << data.sacks << "/t" << data.walks << "/t" << data.hitbyPitch << "/t" << data.battingAvg << "/t" << data.onBase << "/t" << data.Slugging << endl;
    return outdata;
}
ifstream& operator >> (ifstream& indata, recordPlayer data)
{
    indata >> data.id >> data.firstname >> data.lastname >> data.division >> data.team >> data.platApp >> data.atBats >> data.singles >> data.doubles >> data.triples >> data.homers >> data.sacks >> data.walks >> data.hitbyPitch >> data.battingAvg >> data.onBase >> data.Slugging;
    return indata;
}
ofstream& operator << (ofstream& outdata, playerUpdate upd)
{
    outdata << upd.id << "/t" << upd.firstname << "/t" << upd.lastname << "/t" << upd.division << "/t" << upd.team << "/t" << upd.platApp << "/t" << upd.atBats << "/t" << upd.singles << "/t" << upd.doubles << "/t" << upd.triples << "/t" << upd.homers << "/t" << upd.sacks << "/t" << upd.walks << "/t" << upd.hitbyPitch << "/t" << upd.battingAvg << "/t" << upd.onBase << "/t" << upd.Slugging << endl;
    return outdata;
}
ifstream& operator >> (ifstream& indata, playerUpdate upd)
{
    indata >> upd.id >> upd.firstname >> upd.lastname >> upd.division >> upd.team >> upd.platApp >> upd.atBats >> upd.singles >> upd.doubles >> upd.triples >> upd.homers >> upd.sacks >> upd.walks >> upd.hitbyPitch >> upd.battingAvg >> upd.onBase >> upd.Slugging;
    return indata;
}
int main()
{
    recordPlayer stats[1000];

    playerUpdate statsNew[1000];

    ifstream statsOld;//stats2013
    statsOld.open("Master_Data.csv");

    ifstream statsNew;//stats 2014
    statsNew.open("2014_League_Stats_v2.csv");

    ofstream scores;
    scores.open("report.txt");
    //File One
    int fileoneSize = 0;

    statsOld >> stats[fileoneSize].id >> stats[fileoneSize].firstname >> stats[fileoneSize].lastname >> stats[fileoneSize].division >> stats[fileoneSize].team >> stats[fileoneSize].platApp >> stats[fileoneSize].atBats >> stats[fileoneSize].singles >> stats[fileoneSize].doubles >> stats[fileoneSize].triples >> stats[fileoneSize].homers >> stats[fileoneSize].sacks >> stats[fileoneSize].walks >> stats[fileoneSize].hitbyPitch >> stats[fileoneSize].battingAvg >> stats[fileoneSize].onBase >> stats[fileoneSize].Slugging;

    while (!statsOld.eof())
    {
        fileoneSize++;

        statsOld >> stats[fileoneSize].id >> stats[fileoneSize].firstname >> stats[fileoneSize].lastname >> stats[fileoneSize].division >> stats[fileoneSize].team >> stats[fileoneSize].platApp >> stats[fileoneSize].atBats >> stats[fileoneSize].singles >> stats[fileoneSize].doubles >> stats[fileoneSize].triples >> stats[fileoneSize].homers >> stats[fileoneSize].sacks >> stats[fileoneSize].walks >> stats[fileoneSize].hitbyPitch >> stats[fileoneSize].battingAvg >> stats[fileoneSize].onBase >> stats[fileoneSize].Slugging;
    }
    int fileSizeTwo = 0;
    while (!statsNew.eof())
    {
        char updateTypeChar = statsNew.get(); //gets the first character from the line, a DNR character

        if (newPlay(updateTypeChar)) //new player or CREATE 
        {
            fileoneSize++;
            statsNew[fileSizeTwo].update = updateTypeChar;
            statsNew >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].id >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].firstname >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].lastname >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].division >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].team >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].platApp >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].atBats >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].singles >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].doubles >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].triples >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].homers >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].sacks >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].walks >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].hitbyPitch >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].battingAvg >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].onBase >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].Slugging;
            statsOld >> stats[fileSizeTwo].id >> stats[fileSizeTwo].firstname >> stats[fileSizeTwo].lastname >> stats[fileSizeTwo].division >> stats[fileSizeTwo].team >> stats[fileSizeTwo].platApp >> stats[fileSizeTwo].atBats >> stats[fileSizeTwo].singles >> stats[fileSizeTwo].doubles >> stats[fileSizeTwo].triples >> stats[fileSizeTwo].homers >> stats[fileSizeTwo].sacks >> stats[fileSizeTwo].walks >> stats[fileSizeTwo].hitbyPitch >> stats[fileSizeTwo].battingAvg >> stats[fileSizeTwo].onBase >> stats[fileSizeTwo].Slugging;
            fileSizeTwo++;
        }
        if (updatePlay(updateTypeChar)) //returning player or UPDATE
        {
            statsNew[fileSizeTwo].update = updateTypeChar;
            statsNew >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].id >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].firstname >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].lastname >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].division >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].team >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].platApp >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].atBats >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].singles >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].doubles >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].triples >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].homers >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].sacks >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].walks >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].hitbyPitch >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].battingAvg >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].onBase >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].Slugging;
            string pID = statsNew[fileSizeTwo].id;
            int location = playerId(pID, stats, fileoneSize);
            equalThem(stats, location, fileSizeTwo);
            fileSizeTwo++;
        }
        if (delPlay(updateTypeChar)) //didnt return or DELETE
        {
            statsNew[fileSizeTwo].update = updateTypeChar;
            stats >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].id >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].firstname >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].lastname >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].division >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].team >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].platApp >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].atBats >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].singles >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].doubles >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].triples >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].homers >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].sacks >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].walks >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].hitbyPitch >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].battingAvg >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].onBase >> statsNew[fileSizeTwo].Slugging;
            string pID = statsNew[fileSizeTwo].id;
            int whereItIs = playerId(pID, stats, fileoneSize);
            deleteThem(stats, statsNew, whereItIs, fileSizeTwo);
            fileSizeTwo++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is 61 and 78? Also an exact error may help.

Comment: Did you read any other errors? They're pretty descriptive: *error: redefinition of 'statsNew' with a different type: 'ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') vs 'playerUpdate [1000]'*

Answer (score 3):

You have two conflicting declarations of `statsNew`:

```
playerUpdate statsNew[1000];

ifstream statsNew;//stats 2014
```

Comment: OK I understand that i defined it twice. should i not have it defined as an array?

Comment: @hcreal: Well you have used `statsNew` in your code as if it were both an `ifstream` and an array. What you need to do is give these two variables different names, so that the compiler knows which one you're talking about. Then change your code so that you refer to the correct one wherever you have `statsNew` now.

Comment: OK i see what you're saying that makes a lot more sense thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your `statsNew` is defined twice. Once as array of `playerUpdate` and second - as `ifstream`.